# Объединение нескольких словарей

Tags: python

Всем привет. Имеется список (с количеством элементов кратным 7) словарей с одним ключом/значением. Необходимо реализовать слияние словарей внутри листа так, чтобы в каждом словаре было по 7 пар ключ/значений.

Например:

```
#имеется такой список словарей (14 элементов)
dic = [{1:2}, {2:2}, {3:2}, {4:2}, {5:2}, {6:2}, {7:2}, {1:2}, {2:2}, {3:2}, {4:2}, {5:2}, {6:2}, {7:2}]

#желаемый результат:
#print(dic) [{1:2, 2:2, 3:2, 4:2, 5:2, 6:2, 7:2}, {1:2, 2:2, 3:2, 4:2, 5:2, 6:2, 7:2}]
```

Comment: а если ключи не повторяются?

Comment: должны повторяться

Comment: Есть вопрос со схожей темой, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819602/union-of-dict-objects-in-python

Comment: т.е. все `{}` списке продублированы просто и нет уникальных связок ключ:значение?

Comment: продублированы все ключи, значения разные